# How to associate row with a user in Parse.com?

Tags: parse-platform

How to create a column in parse.com such that I can associate each row with a particular user? Also how to protect each row with the user so that others can not perform data modification on that particular row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For most purposes, you want a Pointer column to the user.

For securing your data to that particular user, you'll want to look at object-level access control. You should be able to find most of what you need in the guide: https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#security-object-level-access-control

(There are also similar guides for JS and Android)

Answer (score 0):

Per this link: https://parse.com/questions/data-unique-to-user on the parse site, add a column that is a User to the table you want associate. Then use Parse.user.currentUser() to set that value.